# How to get individual bytes from a register in MIPS assembly?

Tags: assembly, mips

```
value: .asciiz "ABcd1234"

main:
    lw $a0 value #Stores the value in a0 
    li $t0 0     #counter starts a 0
```

Doing this gives me:

```
    $t0 = 0 
    $a0 = 64634241
```

How would I go about getting $t1 = 41 
and then after another loop and incrementing the counter by 1, get $t1 = 42 then 63 and 64 finally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would I go about getting $t1 = 41 and then after another loop and incrementing the counter by 1, get $t1 = 42 then 63 and 64 finally.

I'm assuming that you mean `0x64634241`, `0x41`, `0x42`, `0x63`, and `0x64`.

Isolating the least significant byte can be done by doing a bitwise AND with the value `0xff`. Look up the `andi` instruction in a MIPS instruction set reference.

To get the next byte you would the shift the whole word 8 bits to the right (look up the `srl` instruction), and do another AND. And so on.

Comment: My only concern with this is that when I get the second value, lets say its 0x42 I jump to another place to compare it, and if it passes then I must go to the third value. This gives me troubles due to the fact jumping to a new bitwise AND line. Is there a way to jump to one line specifically by adding a certain offset

Comment: Why not just do the shifting and masking in a loop?

Comment: If I have loop: and $t0 $a0 0x000000FF
                       blt $t0 0x30 test
                       and $t0 $a0 0x0000FF00


test: 
     #do something here

how would I go back to loop to do the second mask if the test passes

Comment: No I mean a loop with a single AND and a single shift. But I didn't find it all that clear what you're _really_ trying to do. If you only want to compare the second byte, why bother extracting the others at all? Just extract the byte(s) you're interested in.